# Auto-scale Background Image

Tags: html, css

I've been searching for solutions for hours but i still can't find a fixed solution to this
when I resize my browser, repeated image will appear. 
https://gyazo.com/7625f773512ff35afb0c09010dca12b1

I tried using background-repeat: no repeat but there will be blank space below which I don't want, I need it to stretch when I resize my browser

```
body {
background-image: url(../Image/Lost.png);
background-size:cover;

}
```

Comment: your image is sufficiently big rite?

Comment: Which browser are you testing this on? See: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size
It would be really helpful to see the full code of your html/css.
The size of the image doesn't matter. It will scale up in any case when background-size: cover is in effect.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? If you add `{background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat}` to what you already have, it should do the trick.

Comment: Hi! Can you please add your complete/minimal code (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe in a jsFiddle? For what we know so far, this could happen for several reasons...

Comment: yes, it's a huge image. i tried padding: 25em; but my words body tag texts will shift according to the padding but it fixes the scaling of image while i resize my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
body {
    background: url(" . . . ");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```